# C# Live data for each tail

Tags: c#

I'm playing with live data. The problem is that it grabs the data at the time executing and display all the data (using foreach). But the time of executing, there is new data that the application hasnt got.

I want the application to continue getting data, but I don't know how to approach this?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync(args).Wait();
}

public static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{

    var credentials = azureLogin;
    var client = new OperationalInsightsManagementClient(credentials);
    client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;


    var searchResult = await client.Workspaces.GetSearchResultsAsync(resourceGroupName, workspeceName, parameters);
    foreach (var result in searchResult.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `parameters` variable, it contains arguments like `end`, `start` and `top`. Use these to specify the rows you want to load instead of loading all rows. Then you load only N rows at a time with a loop.

Comment: can you link me the doc please :)

Comment: @user3622142 http://www.google.com/, thats where I got them, since you didn't say what API you are using...